# Alternate gl_FragColor values from two textures in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

I have two textures, cloud and hill, each with 512 x 512 size, and i intend to create a gl_FragColor output which will obtain the pixel values from the previous textures. In this case, i want to obtain the 1st pixel in `gl_FragColor` from the 1st pixel in the 1st texture, the 2nd pixel in the `gl_FragColor` from the 2nd pixel in the 2nd texture, the 3rd pixel in `gl_FragColor` from the 3rd pixel in the 1st texture an so on. Here is my fragment shader code:

```
 uniform sampler2D tex0;
 uniform sampler2D tex1;

 void main() {
     vec4 cloud = texture2D(tex0, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
     vec4 hill = texture2D(tex1, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
     for (int i=0;i<512;i++) {
       for (int j=0;j<512;j++) {
            if ( j%2 == 0)
                gl_FragColor =  cloud;
            else
                gl_FragColor =  hill;
          }
     }
  }
```

Here's the texture unit setup:

```
t1 = loadTexture("pY.raw", 512, 512);
t2 = loadTexture("pZ.raw", 512, 512);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t2);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t1);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

And here is the uniform setup:
    glUseProgram(program);

```
GLuint t1Location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex0");
GLuint t2Location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex1");

glUniform1i(t1Location, 0);
glUniform1i(t2Location, 1);
```

The problem is, the output for the program is only the hill texture, and i don't know how to fix this. Any suggestion?

Comment: Post your texture unit and uniform setup code.

Comment: Posted in the question section ^^

Comment: And both textures already accessible in GLSL. For example, `gl_FragColor =  cloud;` command without if-condition, will output the cloud texture, while `gl_FragColor =  hill;` without if-condition, will output the hill texture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to do any iterations in your shader. Pixel shader will be called once for every pixel in your object. Instead use gl_TexCoord[0] to get current texture coordinates. Your code should look something like that:

```
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;

void main()
{
    vec4 cloud = texture2D(tex0, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    vec4 hill = texture2D(tex1, gl_TexCoord[0].st);

    if ( int(gl_TexCoord[0].x*512)%2 == 0)
        gl_FragColor =  cloud;
    else
        gl_FragColor =  hill;

    }
}
```

This one should work, even with older opengl:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;

void main(void)
{

    if((gl_FragCoord/32.0- vec4(ivec4(gl_FragCoord/32.0))).x<0.5)
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex0, gl_FragCoord.xy/512.0);
    else
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex1, gl_FragCoord.xy/512.0);
}
```

You can try it out with WebGL at: http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/

Comment: Thanks, I've just realized this point. However, still i get the problem: only the hill texture accessed. The previous fragment shader snippet to differ the odd and even coordinate doesn't work, i think.

Comment: @snowball147 are you sure your shaders work at all? Are you checking for compilation errors? Do some trivial shaders work?

Comment: yes, the shader works. here's the result after applying the shader you have provided: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/qOp1L.png) . I wonder what is the meaning of this condition: ` if((gl_FragCoord/32.0- vec4(ivec4(gl_FragCoord/32.0))).x<0.5) ` and how can i modify this so that the textures just alternate between odd and even pixels in from different texture?

Comment: update, the shader has been working correctly by modifying the if condition to `if((gl_FragCoord/2.0 - vec4(ivec4(gl_FragCoord/2.0))).x<0.5)` . Due to my poor understanding in GLSL, I don't know what's this condition means and why the gl_FragCoord.xy has to be divided by 512, but thanks, I'm going to learn more about gl_FragCoord. Thank you, @Banthar! :)

Comment: `(gl_FragCoord/2.0 - vec4(ivec4(gl_FragCoord/2.0))).x` is just another way of doing modulo. You can do the same with `if(mod(gl_FragCoord.x,2.0)<1.0)`. `gl_FragCoord.xy` is divided by `512.0` because `texture2D` uses values from `0.0` to `1.0` rather than actual texture dimensions. Depending on what you are doing, you might want to replace `gl_FragCoord` with `gl_TexCoord[0]` you will see the difference when you move your object.